# Add Trigger into Magento Tables to update quantity

Tags: mysql, magento, triggers, eventtrigger

I'm trying to add a trigger on table `cataloginventory_stock_item` in magento database to modify the field quantity for all products that have the same part of an sku string.

However the result showing me a sql syntax error.

The trigger is:

```
CREATE TRIGGER UpdateQuantity AFTER UPDATE OF qty ON  `cataloginventory_stock_item`
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    Update cataloginventory_stock_item AS csi
    JOIN catalog_product_entity AS cpe ON cpe.entity_id = csi.product_id
    JOIN catalog_product_entity_varchar AS cpev ON cpev.entity_id = cpe.entity_id
    SET csi.qty = NEW.qty
    WHERE cpev.store_id =2 and AND cpe.sku LIKE concat( '%', (SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(New.sku, '_', 1 ) FROM catalog_product_entity LIMIT 1 ) , '%');
    INSERT INTO logQty VALUES(NEW.qty, old.sku,NOW());
    END
```

Comment: You have a framework for that (which is database abstracted !)  Why trying to attack the DB directly if you can do it with magento standard mecanisms ?

Comment: If you want to do such modification, you should modify catalog inventory reindex process too.

Answer (score 0):

I played with your trigger for a while and fixed some syntax issues but it seems this trigger can not be declared due to the fact thate `cataloginventory_stock_item` does not essentially have an sku field, yet you are referencing it once with Old and once with New keyword.